# Ограничения на название ключей в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Разбираю файл JSON с помощью JSON.parse();
Выясняется такая вещь, что ключ с дефисом не работает.
К примеру, этот ключ выдает ошибку:
"app-categoty": "Игры"

Если поменять на:
"appCategoty": "Игры"
"app_categoty": "Игры"
и даже:
"категорияИгр": "Игры"
Работает без проблем.

В спецификации ограничение на дефис не нашел. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот тебе пример, демонстрирующий тот факт, что в JSON могут быть свойства с дефисом и это не противоречит документации. А вот если ты будешь уже обращаться к свойству как `objectFromJSON.app-category` то получишь ошибку, так как дефис зарезервирован в JS. Следовательно тебе нужно обращаться в этому свойству как `objectFromJSON['app-category']`

Следовательно

```js
const data = {
  'app-category': 'Игры'
};

const JSONData = JSON.stringify(data);
const objectFromJSON = JSON.parse(JSONData);

console.log(objectFromJSON);
```